# console.assert/error stack trace in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

using IE's dev console, I can't seem to get a stack trace for any calls to console.error or console.assert.

I can see the message output to the console fine, but it doesn't say what/where it was called from.

for example: 
[image: no console stack trace]

any solution?   sure for my own code i could write a wrapper, but that doesn't help me for finding IE incompatabilities in 3rd party librieis (like those looking for JSON in IE7)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: no real solution unfortunatly, what i did was just write my own console.assert method to wrap the 'native' one, however that only works if the debug-console is not open.   seems the the IE debug-console will preempt/grab calls to console.assert() if it's open.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at http://log4javascript.org/

> Cross-browser JavaScript logging
>
> log4javascript is designed to work in all major browsers. Internet
>   Explorer 5 onwards on Windows, Firefox 1.0 onwards, Safari 1.2
>   onwards, Opera 8.01 onwards, Konqueror 3.4 onwards and Google Chrome
>   are all fully supported.*

with `JSON.stringify()` and this library you could achieve some kind of stack trace

hope it helps